# Changing input value automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

I´m trying to change an input value automatically. This is what i've got.

```
<input hidden="" id="inp" type="text hidden" value="YES" />

<script type="text/javascript">
function checkInputValue() {
    var files = {
            'YES': 'audio/timbre.mp3',
            'NO': 'audio/timbre2.mp3'
    };
    var sound = new Audio(files[$('#inp').val()]);
    sound.play();
}
checkInputValue();
</script>
```

There is a hidden input in HTML with a default value "YES". I'd like to change this value to "NO" automatically when 2 seconds has passed.

Anyway doing this?

Thanks.

Comment: `setTimeout(function() { $('#inp').val('NO'); }, 2000);`

Answer (score 0):

Simply add this at the bottom of your code

```
setTimeout(function(){
    document.getElementById("inp").value = "NO";
}, 2000)
```

`setTimeout` will execute provided `function` callback after given time. Remember time should be in milliseconds `2000ms == 2s`

Answer (score 0):

You could query the element with `document.getElementById`, and change its value.

```
document.getElementById('inp') //because its 'id' is 'inp'
```

To delay for 2 seconds, use the `setTimeout` function and pass in 2000 milliseconds.

```
setTimeout(function () {
  document.getElementById('inp').value = 'NO'
}, 2000)
```